# What Maths courses do I need to focus on to have a career in "Big Data" areas?

Tags: software-industry

I do not have a CS background, but due to my love for it and self development, I was offered admission into MSc, CS and Applied Maths. This semester, I'm taking a few prereqs. A few days ago, my midterm tests were sent and I did very good (well above 3.5 GPA).

I intention is to develop a career in data related field, Data Science, Data Mining, Financial Analyst, DBA.....
Do I need more of Maths or CS, or a balance of both?

I currently take Calculus this semester, and will take more advanced Maths during and Fall semesters.

P.S. If this is not the best place to ask this sort of questions, please feel free to move to the appropriate section.

Comment: This seems to be off topic per the category of "What to do". Shopping style question

Comment: Is there a reason that you wouldn't ask this question of your academic advisor or someone at your university?  Those folks presumably have a much better idea about your background and aptitude, the particular courses your university offers, what particular employers in your area are looking for, etc.

Comment: Statistics, statistics and more statistics.

Answer (score 2):

You could do any of your stated options, focus on math, CS or both as you wish.

If you are not already studying those fields, you may find it difficult to compete with other students who may have been studying those subjects actively since childhood.

Big data involves more statistics than calculus, so I would recommend studying statistics and logic over other forms of mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

You need two main kinds of focus:

- statistics
- geometry

Statistics is for all of your clusters, regressions, etc

Geometry is so you can plot the data in useful manners.  If you have time, take an HCI course, or something else that teaches perceptual psychology.